# Creating Double Charts

Tags: charts, dygraphs

I am trying to implement a line chart such that when I mouse over any point A, another chart pops up plotting data associated with that point A.

do you know if it is possible to do this in dygraph, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible. You can register a [`highlightCallback`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#highlightCallback) to run code when a point on the main chart is highlighted. Within that callback, you'll want to create a new Dygraph object in a separate div.

Comment: Thanks, danvk!, I got it working, used the example code from http://dygraphs.com/tests/callback.html